# Suppress ENTIRE customer if they contain 1 shipment within a range

Tags: sql, filter, crystal-reports, range, suppress

Hopefully this makes sense. First post here.

I am trying to suppress all instances of a parent while my parameters affect only the child. I run into a problem where I would like to see all customers that had a shipment outside of a date range and ONLY the ***customers*** with shipments outside of that range.

With my current formula below, I will return customers with shipments outside of that date range, but it is possible they have a shipment inside it as well.

Ex.

```
{customer.arcustname} ={?Customer}
AND
{jobshipment.ccdate} <> {?DateRange}
```

DateRange = 7/1/2014 to 7/31/2014

`CUST1's` last shipment was on `6/25/2014`, this record returns true

`CUST2` has a shipment on `7/25/2014`, this record returns false

`CUST2` also a shipment on `6/25/2014`, this record returns true and is displayed on my report. *-not wanted*

I would like my report to display only `CUST1`, since `CUST2` had a shipment inside of that range, but my report is showing `CUST1` and `CUST2` because it is only filtering the `{jobshipment.ccdate}` and not the entire `{customer.arcustname}`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** In my details all I have is {customer.arcustname}. All I want my report to display is a list of customers (by salesperson prompt) who have not ordered in a designated time period. All answers I've seen are only showing the shipments not in the range, where I just want to see the customers who have not had a shipment in the date range. If they had a shipment, I want the {customer.arcustname} omitted from my report.

---

HERE is the raw SQL:
`SELECT customer."armasterid",customer."arcustname",
       salesperson."arsalesname",jobshipment."ccdate" 
FROM  (  ( "public".customer customer LEFT OUTER JOIN "public".salesperson 
       salesperson ON customer.arsalesid=salesperson.arsalesid )  LEFT 
       OUTER JOIN "public".job job ON customer.armasterid=job.armasterid )

       LEFT OUTER JOIN "public".jobshipment jobshipment ON 
       job.ccmasterid=jobshipment.ccmasterid 
WHERE ((#NUMBER CONSTANT# = customer."arsalesid")) AND ((NOT ( 
       (customer."araccountstatus" = 'I') ))) 
ORDER BY customer."arcustname"`

Comment: Are you sure you want this at all? It seems more like you're asking for customers that did not have a shipment in the given range. This makes a difference if a customer (prospect, really) has not yet had *any* shipments, regardless of range. That said, regardless of how you approach it, this is something that's quite difficult in Crystal Reports, and involves pulling a *lot* of data from the server that shouldn't be needed. Do you need to approach the database directly from Crystal Reports? If you can re-work your report to present a data set from your application, it's much simpler.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Crystal and this may not be the most effective way to accomplish what I'd like to achieve. All I really want is to create a Sales tool that shows customers who haven't had a shipment (order) in a specific time range. (the last 30 days for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Below solution works assuming you have a customer group and placed dates in detail as you haven't mentioned report structure.
```

1. Create a formula `@count` to count the occurences of dates that are not in range.

   ```
   if {jobshipment.ccdate} <> {?DateRange}
   then 0
   else 1
   ```

2.Now create a summary field (named {@countSummary}) where we take the sum of @count. Place that in the group footer

3.Write the below supress condition in supress part of group header (Customer group), details and group footer (Customer group).

```
    EvaluateAfter({@count});


 if ({@countSummary}) <> 0
then true
else false
```

Comment: And don't forget to remove the existing record selection formula on `{jobshipment.ccdate}`.

Comment: I have configured everything the way you have mentioned and I am not getting any results. Copying your suppress formula yields "The Field CustomerGroup of type DatabaseField was not found."

Comment: Formula that i gave in my answer is just for sake of explanation.... as i dont have any idea of your database structure. .. please replace the fields of the formula with your relavent fields

Comment: In step 2 you say to take the summary of the @count. Which summary function should I use? Sum?

Comment: Go to the field..right click and then use insert summary.... in that use sunmation option as sum

Comment: I've got this solution working Siva. Exactly as you said, except I had one edit to the formula.

`EvaluateAfter({@count});

if ({@countSummary}<> 0
then true
else false`